# C# Windows application- How to span tag value show in textbox1?

Tags: c#, regex, getattribute, htmlelements

Actually I am want to span the data value show in my `textbox1.Text` area.

This is full code.

```
<td id="yiv9101838563i4" style="padding:0;padding-top:25px;font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;color:#2a2a2a;">Security code: <span style="font-family:'Segoe UI Bold', 'Segoe UI Semibold', 'Segoe UI', 'Helvetica Neue Medium', Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;color:#2a2a2a;">7201</span></td>
```

This is the received code

```
<span style="font-family:'Segoe UI Bold', 'Segoe UI Semibold', 'Segoe UI', 'Helvetica Neue Medium', Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;color:#2a2a2a;">7201</span>
```

I have  checked many sources for a solution but I failed to find a solution so I am waiting anyone good reply.

I want to know how to span value shown in `textbox1.Text` area.

I also tried the code below but that doesn't work.

```
HtmlElementCollection bColl = webBrowser3.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span");
foreach (HtmlElement bEl in bColl)
{
    if (bEl.GetAttribute("style").Contains("font-family:'Segoe UI Bold'"))
        txtlink.Text = bEl.OuterHtml;
}
```

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: 7201 this number I am want show in my textbox but not show any output. Mabe I am mistake somewhere. Pls help me.

Comment: So, to confirm, you want a RegEx to select `7201` from the first string of HTML in your question?

Answer (score -1):

Try this RegEx:

```
<td\s.*?>.*?<span\s.*?>(.*?)<\/span><\/td>
```

The data you want is stored in the **`1st` Capture Group**

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/pE2fI4/1)</kbd>

How it works:

```
<td\s.*?>          # Opening <td> with attributes
.*?                # Optional Data - i.e. Security Code: (Lazy)
<span\s.*?>        # Opening <span> with attributes
(.*?)              # The data you need to Capture - i.e. 7201
<\/span>           # Closing </span>
<\/td>             # Closing </td>
```

Comment: Dear friends I am don't know totally how using regex so can you give me full code then I am going testing. Please do for me I am waiting for your update. Thanks

Comment: @browsersumon StackOverflow is not a free coding service. First, try [Googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=using+regex+in+c%23). Then find some tutorials on using RegEx in C#

Comment: @browsersumon Try [this site](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex) and [this site](http://regexone.com/references/csharp). That is all the info I'll give you.